# What does MMH stand for?

Tags: dpi

I'm looking at some software that does a DPI check based on an upload of an images. It checks the resolution of the image against the specified DPI (300) and MMH (44x88). Does anyone know what MMH stands for?

Comment: Are you sure its MMH? (Do you have a link of that description somewhere?) It's more likely that its 44x88 mm, Is it not something like '44x88 mm h=xx'?

Answer (score 5):

Modified Modified Huffman. It's a method of fax compression.

Comment: Is this something that is still actually used? I'm having a hard time finding any info on "Modified Modified Huffman". All the references Google comes up with are on myspace or in other languages.

Comment: I fax stuff all the time...after I've typed it up on the 'ol Underwood and added a couple of Polaroids. (I'll wait until you dang kids Google "Underwood" and "Polaroid" on your internets...)


The standard is probably still there - it's just a way of ensuring faxed image quality. I am guessing (without knowing the specific software) that they got their start reusing the MMH standard since it was easier than writing their own.

Comment: I'm not sure there is such an algorithm. The basic fax compression algorithm is Modified Huffman (MH). Each line is encoded with this, and then transmitted. To achive better compression, you can use Modified Read (MR). MR encodes the first line with MH, and subsequent lines are delta encoded. MR restricts the number of delta encoded lines to 2 or 4 depending on the fax quality. Then there is an algorithm called Modified Modified Read (MMR), which MR without the limit on sequential delta encoded lines. MMH sounds like a mistaken name for MMR.

Comment: Konica lists it as one of their compression methods:

http://www.konicaminolta.eu/business-solutions/products/copier-print-systems/multifunctional-systems-colour/discontinued-products/bizhub-c10/specifications.html

Comment: So does lexmark: http://support.lexmark.com/index?pmv=print&page=content&locale=en&userlocale=EN_US&id=HO1345

Comment: Also, I prefer to do all my work on a computer, print it, take a photo using my cell phone, and then fax it (after printing it)

Comment: I'm thinking of going back to mimeographs - can't beat the smell... (if you remember getting "fresh" mimeographs hitch your pants up and come shake your fist with me at those young punks on the lawn)

Comment: I worked the crank for my elementary school teacher. No that is not innuendo.

Comment: @lawndartcatcher I could never get my Wacom pen to work properly with those wax stencils, but yeah, the ink was awesome.

Comment: All you crazy kids with your newfangled technology! Back in my day we used smoke signals and they came out just *fine*. It was a big hullabaloo when we upgraded to carrier pigeon, let me tell you.